# I need a RapidMiner Tutor for my Healthcare Quality and Outcomes Analytics class

Tags: learning, rapidminer

I’m currently working on my Master’s in Healthcare Informatics and Analytics and I need help with RapidMiner assignments. Does anyone know where I can find an online tutor? I’ve tried a few websites and they haven’t had tutors for that subject.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going to the [RapidMiner Academy](https://academy.rapidminer.com/) for self-paced online learning.

If you're looking for instructor-led (online) courses, have a look at the [Altair Learning Platform](https://learn.altair.com/course/view.php?id=362).